# SEO 301 redirect limits

Tags: url-rewriting, seo

I'm thinking of doing such structure for accessing some hypothetical page:

/foo/ID/some-friendly-string

The key part here is "ID" that identifies the page so everything that's not ID is only relevant to SEO. I also want everything else that isn't "/foo/ID/some-friendly-string" to redirect to the original link. Eg.:

- /foo/ID ---> /foo/ID/some-friendly-string
- /foo/ID/some-friendly-string-blah ---> /foo/ID/some-friendly-string

But what if somehow these links get "polluted" somewhere on the internet and spiders start accessing them with "/foo/ID/some-friendly-string-blah-blah-pollution" URLs? I don't even know if this can happen, but if, say, some bad person decided to post thousands of such "different" links on some well known forums or some such - then google would find thousands of "different" URLs 301-redirecting to the same page.

In such case - would there be some sort of a penalty or is it all the same to google as long as the endpoint is unique and no content duplicates?

I might be a little paranoid with this, but that's just my nature to investigate explaitable situations :)

Thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of using 301 redirect is correct.

301 redirects are very useful if people access your site through several different URLs. 
For instance, your page for a given ID can be accessed in multiple ways, say:

- http://yoursite.com/foo/ID
- http://yoursite.com/foo/ID/some-friendly-string (preferred)
- http://yoursite.com/foo/ID/some-friendly-string-blah
- http://yoursite.com/some-friendly-string-blah-blah-pollution

It is a good idea to pick one of those URLs (you have decided to be `http://yoursite.com/foo/ID/some-friendly-string`) as your preferred URL and use 301 redirects to send traffic from the other URLs to your preferred one.

I would also recommend adding **canonical** link to the **HEAD** section on the page e.g.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://yourwebsite.com/foo/ID/some-friendly-string"/>
```

You can get more details on 301 redirects in:

- [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) - Configuration > Change of Address
- Google Webmaster Tools Documentation - [301 redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633)

I hope that will help you out with your decisions on redirects.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention very good example, namely, Stack Overflow. The URL of this question is 
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318239/seo-301-redirect-limits` but you can access it with `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318239/blahblah` and will get redirect to the original URL.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Tom. The main concern, however, is if multiple urls redirecting to a single url could be exploited. I'm concerned about this a bit. What if, for instance, a 1000 links redirect to the same page? Would that page be penalized for abuse? In that case it's better for me to issue 404 instead or 301 altogether.

Comment: @Marius, 404 errors would make matters worse. Using 301 is Google's preferred way of identifying default page when multiple (can be 2 or 10 or 1000) links to the page exist. Check Google article at https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633 to get more confidence.

Comment: yes - 2 or 10 links is not be a problem, but your article and other sources i've checked doesn't say if there is a limit to this number, so who's to say a 1000 links wouldn't be too much? Maybe you've read about it somewhere else - would you be able to say with certainty that the number of redirecting links is not limited?

Comment: @Marius, I am not able to provide you any Google document confirming what I just said. About three years ago my company was doing DNS name change along with product catalogue URL restructure (e.g. `/product.jsp?id=X` to `/product-friendly-url`) for US market. At that time we request Google for help and their feedback was to use 301 redirect. Our website was about 5,500 links.

Comment: I guess noone knows for sure how google works :) Thank you, Tom, for your time.